# Passing a variable to a function which takes a smart pointer as a parameter, without that variable being a smart pointer itself.

Tags: c++

Ok, so see how it is possible to pass the address of a variable to a function that requires a pointer like so:

```
void func(int* x)
{
   //some code
}
int y = 9;

func(&y);
```

Is it possible to do something similar to what is above if the function was like the following:

```
 void func(std::unique_ptr x)
 {
     //some code
 }
```

How could I pass it y if I didn't want to make y a unique_ptr for a reason or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function takes a `std::unique_ptr<int>` argument then it expects to take ownership of the variable. Of course, you should not pass it the address of an automatic variable. You would have to create a copy of the value, like so:

```
func(std::make_unique<int>(y));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It doesn't have anything to do with a unique_ptr. A function takes a list of parameters of certain types. That's the only parameters that the function will accept. That's how C++ works.

Your options are:

1. Convert the parameter to the type that the function wants. Not an option if it's a `unique_ptr`.
2. Write an overloaded version of the function that takes a different parameter.
3. Write the function as a template function.

Comment: He could pass `smart-ptr.get()` to pass a non-owning raw pointer to the function though.

Answer (score 0):

If `std::unique_ptr` has a proper constructor, then yes. But you would have to create a template function in that case or, at least, specify the type of your object (in your case - `int`)

Template function:

```
template<typename VarType>
void func(std::unique_ptr<VarType> x)
{
    //some code
}
```

Specific case:

```
void func(std::unique_ptr<int> x)
{
    //some code
}
```